# insert required attribute in a text field only if it is blocked

Tags: javascript

I'd like to use using the *required* attribute in a  text field, only if it is displayed.
The choice or not depends on a radio button.

I can't do it, can someone help me figure out how to do it?

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
  var mail = document.getElementById("mail");
  var newsletter = document.getElementById("newsletter");
  newsletter.style.display = mail.checked ? "block" : "none";

  if (document.getElementById("newsletter").style.display == 'block') {
    newsletter.setAttribute('required', 'required');
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="test.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" size="15" maxlength="15" required>
  <input type="radio" id="mobile" value="mobile" name="contact" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" <input type="radio" id="mail" value="mail" name="contact" required onclick="ShowHideDiv()" <div id="newsletter" style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" size="15" maxlength="15">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your html in this line

`<input type="radio" id="mobile" value="mobile" name="contact" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" <input type="radio" id="mail" value="mail" name="contact" required onclick="ShowHideDiv()" <div id="newsletter" style="display: none">`

Also you are still missing a lot of your logic probably but this is fixing your script that works as expected as per how you wrote your js part.

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
  var mail = document.getElementById("mail");
  var newsletter = document.getElementById("newsletter");
  newsletter.style.display = mail.checked ? "block" : "none";

  if (document.getElementById("newsletter").style.display == 'block') {
    newsletter.setAttribute('required', 'required');
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="test.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" size="15" maxlength="15" required>
  <input type="radio" id="mobile" value="mobile" name="contact" onclick="ShowHideDiv()"> <input type="radio" id="mail" value="mail" name="contact" required onclick="ShowHideDiv()"> <div id="newsletter" style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" size="15" maxlength="15">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">subscribe</button>
</form>
```